# Xamarin Forms bind property to label's text

Tags: xamarin

I have Xamarin Forms xaml:

```
// MainPage.xaml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:BlankAppXamlXamarinForms"
             x:Class="BlankAppXamlXamarinForms.MainPage">

<Label Text="{Binding myProperty}" />

</ContentPage>
```

And I have code behind:

```
// MainPage.xaml.cs
namespace BlankAppXamlXamarinForms {
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public string myProperty= "MY TEXT";

        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            BindingContext = this;
        }
    }
}
```

It should bind myProperty to label's text. However, nothing displays in the label. How to bind myProperty to label's text? (I know I should use ViewModel to be able to notify view about changes of the property but in this example I really just want to bind myProperty from code behind to the label)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to declare that you can "get" the variable.

```
public string myProperty { get; } = "MY TEXT";
```

If you actually want to change this variable in code, your class will need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged, otherwise it will always be "MY TEXT"

Comment: ...and you have to call 'OnPropertyChanged(nameof(myProperty));* after changing the content

Comment: INotifyPropertyChanged wasn't needed in my case, but @copa017 yes, that is crucial. Thanks!

Comment: Hey @robbpriestley, why don't you add the `INotifyPropertyChanged`