# Can i change/bind HorizontalOptions's value in XAML code with Variable in C# backend code?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I have this label in Xamarin form:

```
<Label HorizontalOptions="Start"/>
```

But i want the value of HorizontalOptions become changeable bases on my input into a string variable (string getH) in the backend code.

I tried using binding method, but it does not work.

```
<Label HorizontalOptions="{Binding 
 getH}"/> (XAML code)

getH = "End"; (C# code)
```

Is there any binding method that could work in this case?

Comment: You just have to make it a public variable. Here's an example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39103710/xamarin-forms-bind-property-to-labels-text

Comment: @AZ Software sadly, it only works with "Text". It does not work with HorizontalOptions. I tried it already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you want to bind `string` variabke, you could use `converter` to achieve this.

I created a simple demo , you can refer to it.

MyViewModel.cs

```
   public class MyViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public ICommand BtnResetClickedCommand { private set; get; }
        public MyViewModel() {

            GetH = "End";

            BtnResetClickedCommand = new Command(ResetMethod);
        }

        private void ResetMethod(object obj)
        {
            GetH = "Start";
        }

        string _getH;


        public string GetH
        {
            set { SetProperty(ref _getH, value); }

            get { return _getH; }
        }

        bool SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            if (Object.Equals(storage, value))
                return false;

            storage = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
            return true;
        }

        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }
```

MyTextAlignmentConverter.cs

```
   public class MyTextAlignmentConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value != null)
            {
                string valueAsString = value.ToString();
                switch (valueAsString)
                {
                    case ("EndAndExpand"):
                        {
                            return LayoutOptions.EndAndExpand;
                        }
                    case ("StartAndExpand"):
                        {
                            return LayoutOptions.StartAndExpand;
                        }
                    case ("Center"):
                        {
                            return LayoutOptions.Center;
                        }
                    case ("End"):
                        {
                            return LayoutOptions.End;
                        }
                    case ("Start"):
                        {
                            return LayoutOptions.Start;
                        }
                    default:
                        {
                            return LayoutOptions.StartAndExpand;
                        }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return LayoutOptions.Center;

            }
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Usage:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
             xmlns:testbottomsheet="clr-namespace:TestBottomSheet"
             x:Class="TestBottomSheet.OptionPage">

    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary >
            <testbottomsheet:MyTextAlignmentConverter x:Key="mTextAlignmentConverter">
            </testbottomsheet:MyTextAlignmentConverter>
        </ResourceDictionary>

    </ContentPage.Resources>

    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <testbottomsheet:MyViewModel></testbottomsheet:MyViewModel>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>
  
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!" BackgroundColor="Yellow"  
                VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"   HorizontalOptions="{Binding GetH,Converter={StaticResource mTextAlignmentConverter}}"
                />

            <Button Text="reset" Command="{Binding BtnResetClickedCommand}}"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Note:

In above code ,I implemented interface `INotifyPropertyChanged` for viewmodel `MyViewModel`, and added a `reset` button.When I click the button, we can also change the binded value for variable `GetH` and refresh the UI.

Comment: This looks great. i will try this one out too!

Comment: Dear Sir i am still working very hard on this to pair with my cloud functions, but currently i'm stuck at my firebase cloud function, so i'm not sure about the result yet! anyway thanks for your advices. i will get back to you again this week!

Comment: wow sir i really like the idea of using switch with those LayoutOptions! this really helped me, and i also don't have any problem left as i used to work with INotifyPropertyChanged already. Appreciated your help!

Comment: Oh yes sure Sir. I did it. Anyway appreciated for the new knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

The type of `HorizontalOptions` is not `string` and hence you can't bind to a string. Its of type `LayoutOptions` and you should bind it to a property of type `LayoutOptions` like below,

```
public LayoutOptions GetH { get; set; } = LayoutOptions.Center;
```

and then on the Xaml,

```
<Label HorizontalOptions="{Binding GetH}" />
```

or else if you wish to bind to a `string` for some reason, then you can have a converter. There's already a solution for this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44565205/how-to-bind-horizontaloptions-property-of-label-in-xamarin-forms).

Comment: this sounds really great i will test it out ASAP !